# Bootstrap validation massage with parsley

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, parsley.js

I'm creating a form using parsley validation library. This is the form elements-like:

```
<form class="mt-lg parsleyjs" data-parsley-priority-enabled="false" [formGroup]="form" novalidate="novalidate" (ngSubmit)="checkPasswd()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mail" placeholder="Username" size="16" data-parsley-trigger="change" required="required" [formControl]="form.controls['mail']">
    </div>
  </div>
...
```

When something is wrong, parsley add this code after  element:

```
<ul class="parsley-errors-list filled" id="parsley-id-5">
  <li class="parsley-type">This value should be a valid email.</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

I want these messages appears under each field, not on the right.

Any ideas?

Comment: make a jsfiddle of your code

Comment: What is the structure of the bootstrap validation messages? Can you please provide the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize the layout of the error messages instead of the default `<ul> <li>` structure, you can override the default options like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var parsley_options = {
        errorsWrapper: '<div class="custom-error-wrapper-class"></div>',
        errorTemplate: '<span class="custom-error-template-class"></span>'
    }
    $('#myForm').parsley(parsley_options);

});
```

Validation error message will be displayed in custom structure as:

```
<div id="parsley-id-5" class="custom-error-wrapper-class filled">
<span class="custom-error-template-class parsley-required">This value is required.</span>
</div>
```

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/j8hpj613/)**

[Parsley.js documentation reference link](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/defaults.html)